# Receiving a no such file or directory error: gcloud compute copy-files onto instance from local machine

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, gcloud

```
gcloud compute copy-files /Users/myusername/Pictures/IMG_0382.JPG myusername@my-instance:/var/www --zone asia-east1-c

/Users/myusername/Pictures/IMG_0382.JPG: No such file or directory
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

I am copy-pasting the file directory into my local terminal. What is the deal? Do I have to modify the `.bash` file or something?

Comment: Take a look at [ask].

Comment: Clearly the file you are attempting to copy doesn't exist.  The startup file for Bash is not called `.bash` but this seems unrelated to the Bash environment anyhow.

Comment: Maybe you are running the command in the wrong terminal window.  You need to have a local terminal window (just `bash` running on the computer where the file is to be copied from) and, obviously, it needs to have the `gcloud` toolchain installed.

Answer (score 4):

So, it turns out I was not in the right terminal. Instead of ssh-ing into your instance and *then* issuing the command, you have to open up a fresh terminal window, cd to the appropiate directory (the folder with the desired upload file) and then issue the **gcloud compute copy-files LOCAL...** yada yada. If you are already connected to your instance, that's fine, just open up a new terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

Does this command succeed or fail:
ls -ld /Users/myusername /Users/myusername/Pictures/IMG_0382.JPG

The copy and paste most likely did not do what you expected.

Comment: ls -ld /Users/myusername/Pictures/IMG_0381.JPG
-rw-------@ 1 myusername  staff  439722 17 Jul  2014 /Users/myusername/Pictures/IMG_0381.JPG

Answer (score 0):

The GCP documentation can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files).

To make it work I had to:

1. include `sudo` For permissions
2. delte the `~` specified in the documentation.
3. add zone of my VM

Code:

```
sudo gcloud compute scp [LOCAL_FILE_PATH] [INSTANCE_NAME]:/ --zone [INSTANCE ZONE]
```

Example

```
sudo gcloud compute scp /Users/jb/Downloads/cudnn-8.0-linux-x64-v7.tar instance-1:/home/jb --zone us-west
```